# Rspec respond_to xls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, xls

I have this method in my controller:

```
def index
    @hedge_fund_index_matrix = HedgeFundIndices.matrix
    @hedge_fund_index_headers = HedgeFundIndices.headers
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.xls {
        headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"HedgeFundIndices_#{DateTime.now.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M')}\""
      }
    end
end
```

And, I need to test `respond_to`:

```
it "should respond with javascript" do
    get :index, {:id => @return_value}
    expect(.....).to (....)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test should be like:

```
it "should respond with javascript" do
    get :index, {:id => @return_value}, format: :xls
    expect(response).to be_success
end
```